# Having previously overstayed my Hong-Kong visa, will I be allowed to re-enter for business a year later?

Tags: visas, hong-kong, overstaying, italian-citizens

A year ago I mistakenly overstayed for 5 days and I was forced to return to my country but I didn't want to pay the plane ticket, the HK govt paid and flew me back. Now, I need to go to HK again for business, just a week… Will they let me enter HK? My passport is Italian.

Comment: Your first sentence is confusing: Did you decide to leave yourself? Were you deported? Did you surrender yourself to the authorities in the hope of not paying your return flight? How can any of this happen by mistake?

Comment: What does your removal notice say?

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Long story short, I was on my way to China and by the time I went to the visa office they made me realize that I overstayed 5 days. I made confusion with dates and numbers and I thought I had 5 more days to stay in HK. I went to the police in order to clarify my position   and that was a big mistake because they took me to the immigration and there i was held for 10 days. Since I was so mad about their intention of giving me no more days in HK to make that china visa, i refused to pay for the ticket back here, I made them pay for it.

Comment: It is not a big mistake, as you will end-up in the immigration department anyway since you are overstayed.
BTW, you may want to put your story in the question by editing it, and "what does your removal notice say?"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain how HK will treat this but i'm sure about a similar situation in Australia. When a government sends a visitor back home over their expense, they usually not only pay for the flight back but also impose some fines which a visitor usually is not able to pay. This is done to make sure that such visitor never returns to their country. 
In your case, HK government payed for your flight & i believe they would have imposed some fines over you as well. So in this situation, if you want to get back to HK, you would first have to clear the fines.